# emacs kill process from list

Tags: emacs, emacs24

When using `M-x list-processes` I get a list of processes.

Is there a way to kill them interactively ? For instance by selecting one in the list, then pressing `q` or something similar ?

In case it matters, I am using `emacs 24.5.1` on `osx` with `emacs prelude`.

**Note** : it is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627289/emacs-internal-process-killing-any-command) I want to do it interactively, not from the `mini-buffer` (as understood by @legoscia already).

Comment: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/list-processes+.el

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emacs, internal process killing, any command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627289/emacs-internal-process-killing-any-command)

Comment: @triplee list-processes looks interesting. Are you using it ? Is it on melpa or another repository ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Emacs 25, you can do what you'd expect: in the process list, hit `d` to "delete" the process under point.

---

For earlier Emacs versions, I've been using this little function that works using the minibuffer, not the process list:

```lisp
(defun delete-process-i(p)
  (interactive `(,(completing-read"Kill proc: "(mapcar 'process-name(process-list))()t)))
  (delete-process p))
```

After defining it, you can type `M-x delete-process-i`, and type the name of the process you want to kill, with tab completion.

(I originally wrote it to fit in 140 characters; thus the non-standard layout.)